# Sort with ransack gem using query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I need sorting records, I used the ransack gem with single data in a single table, but when I use querys that involve several tables in the database I can not sort the other tables.

this is my query:

```
def self.busqueda_rep_envases(params)
    query = select("DevEnvases.ID, DevEnvases.CodCli AS Clave,C.Nombre as Responsable, C.NombreCorto as Nombre_Comercial,DevEnvases.Articulo,P.Producto,P1.Producto Envase,SUM(DevEnvases.Cantidad) Entregados,SUM(DevEnvases.Devuelto) Devueltos,SUM(DevEnvases.Cantidad)-SUM(DevEnvases.Devuelto) Saldo ")
           .distinct
           .joins('INNER JOIN Clientes C ON DevEnvases.CodCli=C.IdCli Inner Join Productos P ON DevEnvases.Articulo=P.Clave Inner Join Productos P1 ON DevEnvases.Envase=P1.Clave')
           .where("(DevEnvases.Tipo = :Tipo_Env or :Tipo_Env = '') AND (DevEnvases.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (DevEnvases.DiaO = :diaO or :diaO = '') AND (DevEnvases.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{Tipo_Env: params[:Tipo_Env], rutaId: params[:search], diaO: params[:diaO], idempresa: params[:search6]})
           .group('DevEnvases.ID, DevEnvases.CodCli,C.Nombre,DevEnvases.Articulo,DevEnvases.Tipo,P.Producto,P1.Producto,C.NombreCorto')

    query
  end
```

this is my method in the controller:

```
  def envases
    @search = Devenvase.busqueda_rep_envases(params).search(search_params)
    # make name the default sort column
    @search.sorts = 'Clave' if @search.sorts.empty?
    @envases = @search.result().page(params[:envases]).per(15)
  end
```

this is my search form:

```
  <%= search_form_for @search, :remote=>"true", url: reportes_ruta_envases_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Clave, "Clave","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Responsable, "Responsable","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Nombre_Comercial, "Nombre_Comercial","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Articulo, "Articulo","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Producto, "Producto","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Envase, "Envase","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Entregados, "Entregados","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Devueltos, "Devueltos","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
    <th class="component_name_header_col"><%= sort_link @search, :Saldo, "Saldo","devenvase", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Is there any way to do sorting with ransack via query? Or some other gem or method that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have associations defined in your code (belongs_to, has_many etc), 
**then**

1. change you joins to just have table name:

   ```
   joins(:Clientes, :Productos, :Productos1)....
   ```
2. change sort param to this

   ```
   <%= sort_link @search, :Clientes_Nombre, "Responsable" ....
   ```